# View response headers from an HTTP get API request using Apache hop

Tags: api, http-get, apache-hop

Does anyone know how to view the response headers from an HTTP get API request using Apache hop?  I am using a workflow and the API get request was successful.  I need to view one of the headers and the associated value return from the request.  I searched Apache hop's documentation and could not find anything.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

for reference, this was also discussed with among others @jeoco in the [Hop chat](https://chat.project-hop.org). In short, this is currently not possible, the request was logged as a new feature request in [HOP-4053](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HOP-4053).